# Unittest on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a python script that I run on AWS. The script contains the `lambda_handler(event, context)` function that is called by AWS. Now, I'd like to create a new lambda function that acts as unit test.
A typical unit test schema is defined as:

```
import unittest

def my_function(a):
    return a + 1

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_correct(self):
        self.assertEqual( my_function(1), 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In AWS, the `lambda_handler(event, context)` function is called. How can I make the `unittest_lambda_handler(event, context)` to perform the unit test?

So I am guessing my code (in the unit test script) should look like:

```
import main_lambda_function
import unittest

    def unittest_lambda_handler(event, context):
         #what should this function do?

    class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
         def return_type(self,event, context):
            self.assertTrue(isinstance(main_lambda_function.lambda_handler(event, context),int))
```

Is this the correct approach?If so, what should `unittest_lambda_handler` do?

Comment: Look at the `moto` library. We have used it for unit testing. Here's the link for the library: https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: I'll try the moto library

Comment: An aside, you should be using `self.assertIsInstance(main_lambda_function.lambda_handler(event, context), int)`.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure how many people are aware that in most cases you don't even need a 3rd part library to stub boto3 calls. `Botocore` provides `stubber` out of the box [Reference](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/stubber.html)

*This class will allow you to stub out requests so you don't have to hit an endpoint to write tests. Responses are returned first in, first out. If operations are called out of order, or are called with no remaining queued responses, an error will be raised.*

Answer (score 6):

If you put `unittest.main()` in the lambda handler (`unittest_lambda_handler`), it will not discover your tests and cause the function to always fail since main() is by default calling sys.exit(..) in the end (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/unittest/main.py#L273). You can override that behavior with `unittest.main(exit=False)` but your tests will still not be discovered.

The simplest solution is probably to execute the test directly. So in your example:

```
def unittest_lambda_handler(event, context):
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(
        unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest))

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def return_type(self,event, context):
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(
            main_lambda_function.lambda_handler(event, context),int))
```

Comment: this should be the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `lambda_handler(event, context)` is an integration test. This function is intended to execute the complete workflow of your Lambda script.

You should separate the functions you want to unit test out of the lambda_handler() function:

```
def my_function(a):
    return a + 1

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return my_function(event)
```

Now you can test `my_function` as a normal unit test.

If you wanted to run mock tests on your `lambda_handler` you can create another function that runs your code for testing with mocks:

```
import botocore.session
from botocore.stub import Stubber

def my_s3_function(s3):
    return s3.list_objects(Bucket='test-bucket')

def main_workflow(s3):
    return my_s3_function(s3)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')
    return main_workflow(s3)

def test_mock_handler(event, context):
    # configure mocks here - for example using stubber for boto3
    s3 = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('s3')
    stubber = Stubber(s3)
    return main_workflow(s3)
```

The primary concept is that `lambda_handler()` is only for handling your code when it's run in the full, normal Lambda environment. This code should ideally just do set-up and then invokes other function(s). You can then unit test these isolated functions and write additional handlers to call your code in different test set-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's try to divide the question in 2 parts: the unit tests & the integration tests (or the app as a whole). If you are working in a local project, using virtual env, managing your dependencies and using your favourite IDE, you can always run everything in every moment, meaning that if the unit test wants to verify the function `add_car(car)`, well in theory you don't need to test life cycle. I mean, call the handler to redirect to that capability (that would be another test like a component test or, depending on your design, an integration test).

However, what happen if your `add_car(car)` use dynamo or RDS (any other AWS service)? Well for those cases and for integration & component test you can use **placebo**: https://github.com/garnaat/placebo. As their description says: *"mock boto3 calls that look just like normal calls but actually have no effect at all"*. There is a really good example in this article: https://serverless.zone/unit-and-integration-testing-for-lambda-fc9510963003. Also there are some other libraries like https://github.com/spulec/moto, you may find examples here https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/105256/moto.mock_ec2

Also, take a look of the recommendations that the guys from ClaudiaJS (I know is Javascript but the concepts are really good) about designing testable Lambdas functions. https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/designing-testable-lambdas.html

Good luck!

Comment: which one do you prefer? placebo or moto?

Answer (score 1):

[localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) may be of interest here.

> LocalStack provides an easy-to-use test/mocking framework for developing Cloud applications. Currently, the focus is primarily on supporting the AWS cloud stack.